# Can't submit Ajax post in django. MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django, ajax

I have an HTML document with a  texture

```html
<form id = "msgform"  method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea  id = "msg" name = "msg" > </textarea>
    <button type="submit" >Send</button>
</form>
```

And I have an Ajax form submission

```js
  $(document).on('submit', '#msgform', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'{% url "group" %}',
      data:{
        value:$('#msg').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      
      success:function(){     
      }

    })
  }
```

My Django view

```py
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    x = request.POST['value']
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/" + slug)
```

The program was working before the Ajax was added. When I try to submit text, the program can't find the variable "value" even though I declared it. It says, MultiValueDictKeyError. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the django view as well.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could change the behaviour of the button to send the ajax.

Make your `data` dictionary keys are strings.

```
data:{
    'value':$('#msg').val(),
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
  },
```

Change your submit button to:

```html
<button type="button" id="submit_form">Send</button>
```

Then change event type

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_form', function(e){ 
   $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'{% url "group" %}',
  data:{
    value:$('#msg').val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
  },
  
  success:function(){     
  }

});
```

Comment: This does not fix it. I think the problem is related to the fact that the default form submission is still happening. hopefully, someone knows how I can avoid the default form submission. I have used the prevent default method, but it does not seem to be working.